# XMLParsing error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting XML parsing error when trying to implement download function in web application in C#. The same code is working in another web form.

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();

cn.ConnectionString =ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString.ToString();
cn.Open();

String abc = null;

SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("select User_ID from Mgmt where S_Name='" + DropDownList1.Text + "'", cn);

SqlDataReader dr = cm.ExecuteReader();

if (dr.Read())
{
    abc = dr.GetString(0).ToString();
}

dr.Close();
cm.Dispose();

String ab = null;

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Result from Result where Clg_ID='" + abc + "'and Student_ID='" + TextBox1.Text + "'", cn);
SqlDataAdapter drr = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();

drr.Fill(ds);

ab = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();

Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename='"+ab+"'");
Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/Result/"+ab));
Response.End();

cn.Close();
```

Comment: on what line of code do you get the error? A side note - your code is wide open for SQL injection atack.

Comment: There is no warning just when on running this code the output on web browser is an xml parsing error.

Comment: Does file with name stored in variable `ab` exist in the `~/Result` location?

Comment: What exception do you get? What does your data look like?

Comment: Yes ab contains the file name. This whole code is working perfectly in another web form calling the same file.

Comment: Is it possible that something has already been written to the response? Try adding `Response.Clear()` before `Response.ContentType = ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a possible answer for my own question after lot of struggle. It is not an accurate answer. I just switched my computer and then this error was no more and on returning back to my previous computer then also error was resolved. I still don't know what caused the error and how it got solved.